# Significado de máximas em Memórias Póstumas de Brás Cubas

Tags: significado, ditados, proverbios, literatura

Não consegui entender o significado de alguns provérbios/máximas/ditados populares presentes no livro.

**Memórias Póstumas de Brás Cubas:
Capítulo CXIX (Parêntesis)**

"Matamos o tempo; o tempo nos enterra."

"Não te irrites se te pagarem mal um benefício: antes cair das nuvens, que de um terceiro andar."

Comment: Olá! Seja bem-vindo ao PortugueseSE. Imagino que sua pergunta ficaria melhor formulada e com mais chances de boas respostas se você criasse uma nova pergunta pra cada um dos provérbios, bem como se você fornecer um contexto mais elaborado, como o trecho completo de onde você retirou as passagens ou alguma pesquisa que você tenha feito antes de postar a pergunta aqui.

Comment: Vinícius, isto são três ´(ou quatro) perguntas distintas, e ficariam melhor em perguntas separadas: podes editar esta pergunta, deixando só um ditado, e criar perguntas novas para os outros ditados. As duas d' *O Cortiço* são as únicas que se justificam ficar juntas, pois ocorrem no mesmo contexto e dizem respeito ao mesmo assunto. As das *Memórias*, mesmo estando no mesmo capítulo, são completamente independentes. Poderias incluir o ditado/máxima no título da pergunta também.

Comment: @James, lol, qual é o equivalente em português para *great minds think alike?*

Comment: @Jacinto Não sei um equivalente, pois não lembro de já ter ouvido essa expressão, mas realmente coube como uma luva. :)

Comment: great minds think alike -> Mentes brilhantes pensam do mesmo modo.

Comment: @Jacinto Farei isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Matamos o tempo; o tempo nos enterra."

> Matar o tempo significa  [**entreter-se**](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/matar%20o%20tempo) ou **realizar alguma atividade, geralmente não-produtiva, enquanto as horas não passam**. Por exemplo, fazer palavras cruzadas enquanto esperamos uma chamada para embarque.   "O voo vai atrasar três horas. Preciso arrumar alguma coisa para **matar o tempo**."
>
> Já "o tempo nos enterra" significa que **mais cedo ou mais tarde, o tempo se encarregará de que sejamos enterrados.**
>
> O ditado todo então significa **"Podemos matar o tempo no sentido literário, mas o tempo nos mata no sentido literal."**

"Não te irrites se te pagarem mal um benefício: antes cair das nuvens, que de um terceiro andar."

> "ficar (com a cabeça) nas nuvens" significa **sonhar, fantasiar, ficar deslumbrado, [estar fora da realidade; longe dos fatos reais](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/significado/estar+com+a+cabe%E7a+nas+nuvens/6704/)** Cair das nunvens, obviamente, significa **"por os pés de volta no chão", "enfrentar a realidade", [**sofrer uma decepção, desapontamento ou desilusão](http://dicionariocriativo.com.br/analogico/cair_das_nuvens/substantivo/ceticismo)**

O ditado então significa "é melhor descobrir que foi enganado, do que ser ferido fisicamente ou morrer."

Comment: "o tempo nos enterra" significa que uma hora seremos cobrados por não termos feito nada, ou veremos o resultado de não termos feito nada

Comment: cair das nuvens = cair na real

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to clarify two of those:

> Matamos o tempo; o tempo nos enterra.

`Matamos o tempo` can be translated literally as "to kill time", ie, do nothing usefull while you're getting older and older.

`O tempo nos enterra`- Literally, Time (capital letter) buries us, we die a little bit each day.

> Não te irrites se te pagarem mal um benefício: antes cair das nuvens, que de um terceiro andar.

`Não te irrites se te pagarem mal um benefício` - Don't get upset if you are poorly paid (I'm not sure how to interpret this given this short context).

`Antes cair das nuvens, que de um terceiro andar` - This is very abstract and gives margin to other interpretations. But I'll assume it means the following: It's better to "fall from the clouds" and die instantly (thus having a great thrill/adventure in the process), than just to survive a terrible accident which may turn you into a vegetal. Well, just think about some 70's rock starts who died before their 30's.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Mno, *cair das nuvens* is an idiom; it means to have a great disillusion: *Hillary caiu das nuvens quando os votos começaram a ser contados*. So, what Machado de Assis means, is that it is better to receive bad and unexpected news than to be physically hurt at an accident.