# Agreeing with the complement not the subject: isto são tres perguntas

Tags: concordância-verbal

I always find interesting those things that native speakers do automatically but which they aren’t sure about why they do them. This is one of those.

There are times in Portuguese when a linking verb agrees in number not with its subject but with its predicate complement.  What got me thinking about it was [this comment by Jacinto](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/4014/#comment10301_4014) that included:

> isto são três (ou quatro) perguntas distintas

It seems to me this can occur in other scenarios, too, such as this one:

- Os estranhos somos nós.

Notice how *ser* formally agrees not with its subject of *os estranhos*, but with its predicate complement of *nós*.  Portuguese works quite differently from English in this regard, because [in English the verb agrees only with its subject never with its complement](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/17766/2085).  However, [Spanish works like Portuguese](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19211/457), for whatever that’s worth. Perhaps we can blame Latin? :)

This is really only one question, but here are my thoughts:

1. Why does this happen?  Does it always happen, or is there some latitude?
2. If it does not always occur, does the choice in agreement mean something one way or the other?
3. Does having a non-concrete subject like *isto* or *tudo* make it more likely?

#### Examples

Searching around in Google Books, I find these samples. These being to feel much more like inversion to me than a mismatched subject.

- **A sombra não somos nós**, mas uma espécie de fotografia em branco e preto apenas em forma de silhueta.
- **O  ponto** nevrálgico de todo o problema **somos nós mesmos**, que nos debatemos nas angústias da vida e nas inquietações da existência.
- Devemos, portanto, enfatizar a ideia de que “nós” não somos o estado; **o governo não somos “nós”**.
- Como a **igreja somos nós** [...]
- [...] **membro** de um grande corpo **somos nós**.
- Cale a boca, quem decide isso somos nós.

---

## Reference Update

I’ve found a reference about this at https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/902 :

> À pergunta *O que é o bolo alimentar?* deve responder-se *O bolo alimentar são os alimentos depois de mastigados e ensalivados.* Regra geral, o nome predicativo do sujeito concorda em género e número com o sujeito (ex.: *O João é famoso, A Maria é famosa, O João e a Maria são famosos*). Todavia, no caso em apreço, **esta regra geral não se aplica e a concordância faz-se com o nome predicativo do sujeito** (*os alimentos depois de mastigados e ensalivados*), que identifica e realça os elementos que compõem o sujeito como um todo (*o bolo alimentar*).

Well yes, that’s the question isn't it?  So that source is saying that it indeed works differently, but not much about why.

What I’d most to find, if possible, is a Portuguese resource that addresses this curious matter in a way similar to how the Spanish do so [in sections 37.6i+j etc from the *Concordancia* chapter in la Real Academia’s 2009 Grammar](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=OGVVvzzgWwAhLEzv) of their language.

Although some of that chapter written about Spanish probably makes some amount of sense for Portuguese, too, plenty of it clearly does not, so I’m still looking for a purely Portuguese reference about this that’s more substantial in its treatment than what’s at Flip.PT.

Comment: Related and possible duplicate: http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/3315/38

Comment: This is a good question. It seems to me that "os estranhos somos nós" is **an inversion of** "nós é que somos os estranhos" and I'm not sure whether **"os estranhos"** is the subject of the original sentence.  When would I say "os estranhos somos nós"?  Perhaps when somebody complained "Essa gente estranha bem que podia não estar aqui.  And I would reply "Olha, os estranhos somos nós" which is another way of saying "nós é que somos os estranhos aqui."

Comment: There are several instances of this construction in Portuguese, like "O inferno são os outros" a well-known quotation by Sartre. ("l'enfer, c'est les autres" in French and "L'inferno sono gli altri" in Italian) which to me doesn' t simply mean "Os outros são o inferno" but rather "Os outros **é que** são o inferno"

Comment: @Centaurus Curious that French had a singular *c’est* there (not a plural *ce sont*) like English would while Italian had a plural *sono* there the way Portuguese or Spanish would. It does indeed feel like the predicative complement is the actual subject to me, but I cannot tell whether that’s because my instinct as an English speaker is that whatever governs the verb is its subject almost by sheer definition. I’d have no problem generating *O nosso problema aqui és tu* using *és* to agree with *tu* not with *problema*, but that is instinctive to me due to Spanish, not something I understand.

Comment: When you stop to think about it, it's a strange construction though I can't tell why it's so.  To use "Os estranhos são nós", however, sounds completely wrong.  I believe it has something to do with inverted parts of the sentence.  "Os estranhos (não são eles), somos nós." or "O inferno (não sou eu) são os outros."  Let's wait and if someone comes up with a better explanation.

Comment: Tchrist, "O bolo alimentar são os alimentos depois de..." may be grammatical and easier to understand, but I would say it differently. If I had to, I'd probably say "O bolo alimentar **é** formado pelos alimentos depois de..." or "O bolo alimentar nada mais **é** do que os alimentos depois de..." or "Bolo alimentar **é** a denominação que damos aos alimentos depois de mastigados e ensalivados."  The last example is more likely to be found in textbooks.

Comment: O inglês segue o modelo (nome)(verbo)(predicado); O português permite montar a frase de outras formas (predicado)(verbo)(nome) Os estranhos somos nós (verbo)(nome)(predicado) Somos nós os estranhos, entre outras com vírgulas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Respondo acerca da construção

> - "Os estranhos somos nós"

Esse tipo de construção gramatical é muito comum na língua portuguesa.

> - "O inferno são os outros"
> - "Os culpados somos nós"
> - "O chefe sou eu"
> - "O culpado sou eu"

Quando o verbo está conjugado de modo a concordar com qualquer um dos dois que possa ser o sujeito da frase (os estranhos x eles; o culpado x ele), a concordância ocorre por coincidência já que ambos estão na mesma terceira pessoa, do singular ou plural.

> - "Os culpados são eles"
> - "O mal-educado é ele"
> - "O inferno é o mundo em que eu vivo"

Mas nos casos em que aparentemente não há concordância (Os estranhos somos nós, por exemplo) o que ocorre?  **Trata-se de uma inversão das frases**:

> - "Nós **é que** somos os estranhos" (não eles)
> - "Nós **é que** somos o inferno" (não os outros)
> - "Eu **é que** sou o chefe" (não você)

E há uma diferença sutil entre **"nós somos os estranhos"** e **"nós é que somos os estranhos"**.  A segunda frase pretende afirmar que não são aquelas outras pessoas os estranhos. Somos nós.  **E usamos a inversão "os estranhos somos nós" com o mesmo objetivo, dar ênfase a quem é o estranho.**  Uma vez que a frase original seria "nós somos os estranhos", havendo a inversão, o verbo continua concordando com o sujeito original.

Comment: I begin to think you’re right that this is actually a case of inversion.

Comment: O problema com a tese da inversão (isto é, o sujeito vem depois do verbo, e portanto o verbo concorda com o SN que vem depois dele, mas continua a concordar com o sujeito) é que não parece ser sempre o caso. Por exemplo, o citado "isto são três perguntas": não vejo como possa ser uma inversão de "três perguntas são isso".

Comment: @LuísHenrique   Minha resposta não aborda "isto são três perguntas".  Foi a primeira coisa que eu escrevi.

Answer (score 2):

Vou abordar apenas o tipo de frases dos teus exemplos—*isto são três perguntas* e *os estranhos somos nós*—que são casos relativamente simples. E para pôr alguma ordem na discussão vou adotar a distinção que a *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian (2013) faz entre sujeito semântico e sujeito gramatical. Dizem eles (volume 2, p. 1284, nota de pé de página):

> Não confundir a noção de sujeito semântico da predicação—tipicamente um SN que introduz a entidade sobre a qual o predicado produz um comentário—com a noção de sujeito gramatical de uma oração—o SN que concorda em pessoa e número com o verbo, no caso de a oração ser finita ou de infinitivo flexionado […] nem sempre o sujeito de uma predicação é o sujeito gramatical da oração

Depois, precisamente a propósito do verbo ser, apresentam exemplos em que não há essa coincidência de sujeitos (p. 1329):

> (73) a. Agora são cinco da tarde.
>   b. Hoje é segunda-feira.
>
> […]
>
> [7] Nas orações copulativas de (73), existe uma discrepância entre o sujeito semântico da predicação—as expressões temporais dêiticas pré-verbais—e o sujeito gramatical, que determina a concordância em pessoa/número do verbo de cópula—a expressão temporal pós-verbal. Aceitando o critério de que o sujeito gramatical de uma oração é o constituinte que determina a concordância verbal, nestes exemplos é, pois, o constituinte predicativo que funciona como sujeito gramatical.

Dizer que por definição o sujeito gramatical é aquilo que concorda com o verbo pode ser circular, mas esta abordagem dá-nos um critério para tentar identificar o sujeito semântico: a expressão que representa a entidade sobre a qual o predicado tece um comentário.

Vejamos primeiro as frases do tipo *os estranhos somos nós*, ou seja, orações com um pronome pessoal ligado pelo verbo *ser* a outra coisa. Nestes casos o verbo concorda sempre com o pronome pessoal:

> Os estranhos somos nós.
>   O culpado és tu.
>   O presidente da junta sou eu.
>   Tu és as minhas esperanças.

Na abordagem da *Gramática* da Gulbenkian, o pronome pessoal é sempre o sujeito gramatical. O sujeito semântico pode coincidir com ele ou não. No exemplo seguinte eu diria que coincide:

> (a)—A nossa rua hoje está cheia de estranhos.
>   (b)—Pois é; a bem dizer, aqui os estranhos somos nós.

Aqui a oração *os estranhos somos nós* tece um comentário sobre nós e implicitamente sobre os outros, dizendo que nós é que somos os estranhos, e o que os outros não o são. Aliás, (b) é semanticamente equivalente a:

> (b1)—Pois é; a bem dizer, aqui nós é que somos os estranhos.

E também poderíamos reformular o diálogo com o adjetivo *estranhos* em vez do substantivo, sem alterar minimamente o significado, e reforçando a impressão que *nós* é que é o sujeito semântico:

> (a2)—A nossa rua hoje está cheia de pessoas estranhas.
>   (b2)—Pois é; a bem dizer, aqui estranhos somos nós.

Mas no exemplo seguinte, *aquelas pessoas*, e não *nós*, é que parece ser o sujeito semântico; mas *nós* continua a determinar a concordância verbal:

> (c)—Olha esta fotografia com os primos todos. Mas quem são aquelas pessoas lá ao fundo? Serão os vizinhos?
>   (d)—Aquelas pessoas somos nós; não são nada os vizinhos.

Aqui (b) tece um comentário sobre “aquelas pessoas lá ao fundo”, mais do que sobre nós ou os vizinhos. Aliás neste caso não soaria nada natural responder:

> (d1)—Nós é que somos aquelas pessoas.

Admito que este exemplo dê margem para outra interpretações. Já o outro tipo de frase é muito claro. Quando temos o pronome indefinido *isto, isso* ou *aquilo* ligado pelo verbo *ser* a outra coisa, o verbo concorda com a outra coisa. Neste caso como temos duas terceiras pessoas, a questão da concordância resume-se ao número:

> Isso são três perguntas.
>   As perguntas são isto.
>   Isto são rosas, Senhor.

No entanto é o pronome indefinido que é claramente o sujeito semântico. Quando eu disse “isto são três (ou quatro) perguntas”, estava a tecer um comentário sobre o post, que referenciei com “isto”. Aquela brincadeira que fizemos antes—que (b) *os estranhos somos nós* é equivalente a (b1) *nós é que somos os estranhos*—neste caso aponta no sentido contrário. Não se diz *as três perguntas é que são isto*, mas as frases seguinte são normalíssimas:

> —Isso é que são as perguntas?
>   —Não, homem! Isto são as respostas; aquilo ali é que são as perguntas.

Não tenho a certeza, mas isto parece ser mais ou menos a mesma coisa que o teste 2 da resposta do Artefacto à [pergunta do pomar](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3315/concord%C3%A2ncia-em-n%C3%BAmero-com-o-verbo-ser-o-pomar-%C3%A9-cinco-%C3%A1rvores-ou-o-pomar-s%C3%A3?noredirect=1&lq=1). Ele diz que “não é possível clivar o SN em posição pré-verbal nas frases invertidas” (com sujeito depois do verbo), apenas nas frases canónicas (sujeito + verbo + qualquer coisa). Na frase (b) isto reforça a ideia que *nós* é o sujeito: podemos dizer *somos nós que somos os estranhos* mas não **são os estranhos que somos nós*. Mas esta clivagem é perfeitamente possível com o *isso, isto* e *aquilo* pré-verbais:

> —É isso que são as perguntas?
>   —Não, homem! Isto são as respostas; é aquilo ali que são as perguntas.

Answer (score 0):

Diferentemente do Inglês, do qual o completemento deve seguir o sujeito, Português funciona de uma outra forma:

> Nós somos os culpados

*This is our fault*

> Essa coisa nos deixa loucos

*This thing drives us nuts*

Como você pode ver, *'deixa'* é usado no singular, apesar de que o sujeito é *'nós' (plural)*,, isso acontece porque *'Deixa'* é o complemento do objeto *'Essa'*, do qual é singular. E *loucos* é o completo do sujeito *Nós*, por isso se encontra no plural.

Outros exemplos:

> Esse gato nos fez muito felizes
>
> Talvez esse problema os levou à loucura